# Return multiple lists in Python function

Tags: python, list, function, return

I am new to Python, and am trying to create a function which creates lists with different material parameters from user inputs as shown in the code below.

```
def material():
    layers = int(raw_input("State the number of material layers in the wall (0 for default material): "))

    rho = [] # Density [kg/m3]
    c = [] # Heat capacity [J/(kg K)] 
    k = [] # Heat conductivity [W/(m K)]
    #a = [] # Thermal diffusivity [m2/s]
    d = [] # Thickness of material [m]

    # Saveing material properties
    if layers == 0:
        rho.append(2300)
        c.append(900)
        k.append(1.6)
        d.append(3.2)
        layers = 1

    else:
        for i in range(layers):
            print "\n" "Define thermal properties for material", i+1,"(starting from left)"
            rho.append(float(raw_input("Density [kg/m3]: ")))
            c.append(float(raw_input("Heat capacity [J/(kg K)]: ")))
            k.append(float(raw_input("Heat conductivity [W/(m K)]: ")))
            d.append(float(raw_input("Thickness [m]: ")))

    return ???
```

How should I return *rho, c, k, d* and *layers* so I am able to e.g. print – or use the value of – e.g. the second item in the list of *d*?

```
print d[1]
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> How should I return rho, c, k, d and layers [...] ?

Simply do it:

```
return rho, c, k, d, layers
```

And then you'd call it like

```
rho, c, k, d, layers = material()
print d[1]
```

Note that the more stuff you're returning, the more likely it is you're going to want to wrap it all together into some structure like a `dict` (or `namedtuple`, or class, etc.)

Comment: Obs.: This feature is actually returning a `tuple` and then doing a multiple assignment statement. You can also use `S = material(); print S[3][1]` to achieve the same result for example.

Comment: @OdraEncoded: very true.  I tend not to use tuple indexing for heterogeneous return results because it's too easy for me to mix up which variable correponds to which index.

Comment: God, you are fast out there. Thank you so much. I can see that my problem was more about how to call the function – but I got it now. Thanks again, everyone. Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

`return` can return multiple values if you separate them with commas:

```
return rho, c, k, d, layers
```

This will make `material` return a tuple containing `rho`, `c`, `k`, `d`, and `layers`.

Once this is done, you can access the values returned by `material` through unpacking:

```
rho, c, k, d, layers = material()
```

Here is a demonstration:

```
>>> def func():
...     return [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]
...
>>> a, b, c = func()
>>> a
[1, 2]
>>> b
[3, 4]
>>> c
[5, 6]
>>> a[1]
2
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def return_values():
    # your code
    return list1, list2
```

and get the value like below

```
value1, value2 = return_values()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function_returning_multiple_list():
  l1=[]
  l2=[]
  l3=[]
  return (l1,l2,l3)


def another_fucntion():
  list1,list2,list3=function_returning_multiple_list()
  print list2
```

Comment: Note that there is no need for the parenthesis in the return statement.